# Keyboard show/hide event not firing in Cordova 5.1.1

Tags: cordova, android-softkeyboard, cordova-plugins, android-event, cordova-5.0.0

I just updated my cordova from 4.3.0 to 5.1.1 and it seems that the keyboard event is not firing up  previously,

```
 document.addEventListener("showkeyboard",function() {
   }
```

and

```
 document.addEventListener("hidekeyboard",function() {
 }
```

where working but after upgrading it stopped working 
,i am also using a keyboard plugin ionic keyborad it has its own events

```
 window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', keyboardShowHandler);
```

they are also not firing ,please help me with the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that from cordova-android-4.0.0 these events have been removed and they are suggesting to use plugin such as [ionic-keyboard-plugin](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard) for that events

[Ref-src](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/15/cordova-android-4.0.0.html) see in other changes section

Comment: Oh my god... I need those show\hide keyboard events on Android... any ideas?